# Returning an int array with object array return type

Tags: java, casting

I am doing something like this :

```
public Object [] getApple() {
    return new int[4];
}
```

But Java compiler does not allow this. 
It says cannot convert from int[] to Object[].

While If I do something like this :

```
public Object  getApple() {
    return new int[4];
}
```

It compiles fine. 
Can anyone explains why int [] cannot be cast to Object [] implicitly?

Comment: `Object[]` is not the same as `int[]` because you're only thinking about the types of the elements, not the arrays themselves. They're not the same; whereas an `Object[]` is a child of `Object` (everything is) and so that compiles.

Comment: int is primitif and Object not so is why you can't return it. If you want return int I suggest you to use Integer[4].

Comment: Object[] expects an array of objects to be returned. While an int array (int[]) is a single object. If you would for example return 2 or more int arrays they would fit in an object array

Answer (score 3):

`int`s are not `Object`s, that is why. They are **primitive data types**, they play a special role and are not in the class tree with the *all-parent* `Object`.

The second example works because the `int[]` array itself can be interpreted as `Object`.

---

You can use the wrapper class `Integer` though, which is a subclass of `Object`:

```
public Object[] getApple() {
    return new Integer[4];
}
```

You can work with it similar to an `int[]` due to auto-boxing. So if you do

```
Integer[] values = (Integer[]) getApple();
values[1] = 5;
```

Java will automatically box the `5` into the corresponding `Integer` object that represents `5` and then add this `Integer` to the array.

Same happens if you do

```
int val = values[2];
```

Java will unbox the value from the `Integer` object and give you an `int` since `val` is of type `int`.

Note that auto-boxing does not work for arrays, so Java won't automatically convert your `int[]` into an `Integer[]`. It only works for `int` to `Integer` and vice versa (analogously for the other primitives like `double` etc).

Answer (score 2):

That is because `array` is an `Object` in Java. Hence when you try to return an int array as an Object, it was accepted.

However, when you tries to return an ***int array*** as ***array of Object*** it will be rejected because you are returning int array (an object) when the method return type is expecting (array of object).

```
public Object[] getApple()    //expecting (array of object) 
{  
    return new int[4];        //returning array (an object) Type mismatch!
}
```

If you run the following, it will be compilable:

```
public Object[] getApple()    //expecting (array of object) 
{  
    return new int[4][4];     //returning array of array (array of object) O.K!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning a primitive int[] array, which is not a subtype of Object[]. You can return Integer[] instead.

Comment: An int array is definately an object. A single object, and a single object is not the same as an object array

Comment: OK, my mistake, I guess I had to say primitive int is not an object.

Comment: Uhm, any int for example int i = 9; is an object. Whitfin made a comment above, everything is a child of Object

Comment: As far as I know, reference types are subclass of Object. primitive type, int can be passed wherever its corresponding Integer object is expected via boxing.

Comment: So if I have a return type of Object I can't return something of type primitive?

Comment: Sure it can return primitive. primitive type gets boxed into its wrapper class. For instance, int to Integer. However it still does not mean that primitive is an object. There are two rules to objects. You can call methods on them and objects can be null. None of these relate to primitives. It's just Java's boxing/unboxing feature that tricks us thinking that primitives are objects.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a specific type, and arrays of a subclass are not themselves subclasses of array of a superclass.